# Installing FIWARE Sanity Checks in my own premise

Tags: fiware, fiware-health

I want to install the *FIWARE Sanity Checks* in order to check my own FIWARE Lab node and I see that there are two subcomponents in the repository. Why are there two subcomponents on *FIWARE Health* repository? Which one should I install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FIWARE Health consists of two subcomponents:

- a test execution engine which runs all Sanity Checks on each FIWARE Lab
  node in order to validate its capabilities and get the 'Sanity
  Status'.
- and web dashboard to show all generated test reports and each node
  status.

The execution engine is the [FIHealth Sanity Checks subcomponent](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-health/tree/master/fiware-region-sanity-tests) and the web dashboard is the [FIHealth Dashboard subcomponent](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-health/tree/master/dashboard). The components are independently each other. You can install only the **FIHealth Sanity Checks** if you are not interested to publish your results in a web server (dashboard). Running **FIHealth Sanity Checks** you will get test results as xUnit and/or HTML. You can use optional scripts included in the repository to process these results and get the 'Sanity Status' of your node.

Of course, you can run all sanity tests only on your node (after setting in your environment the OpenStack credential variables), executing following script:

```
   $ ./sanity_checks MyNodeName
```

To know more about these subcomponents and how can you install them, take a look at the FIHealth Sanity Checks and FIHealth Dashboard documentation.